# Failing to Deserialize JSON to HashMAp<String, POJO> with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having trouble correctly deserialising JSON into POJO's that are in a Map

I connect to a webservice that returns a JSON dictionary with an arbitary number of keys that looks like

```
{ 
    "arbitray_key_name": {
        "foo_sticks": "objectName"
        "bar_socks": ["A", "B"]
    },
    "another_key_name: {
        "foo_sticks": "differentName"
        "bar_socks": ["C", "D", "E"]
    }
    ...
}
```

I am using Gson to deserialise into a HashMap.  If I do

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

with the above JsonData (minus the ... obviously) then I get exactly what I expect which is a HashMap of 2 items, keys of 'arbitray_key_name', 'another_key_name', where each value is itself a Map with the correct key/value information for the child objects.

However I have a POJO class that I want to deserialise the values into which looks like

```
public class FooInfo {
    @Key("foo_sticks")
    public String fooSticks;

    @Key("bar_socks")
    public String[] barSocks;
}
```

If I try and do

```
HashMap<String, FooInfo> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, FooInfo>>() {}.getType());
```

then I get back a HashMap of two items where each value is a FooInfo but the fields in both the FooInfo objects are null, the Json hasn't been mapped into the objects.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to work in this case.  However it breaks some other code that is deserialising to the POJO (a HTTP endpoint that is just returing a single FooInfo object not keyed in a dict).

Going back to the version of the POJO with `@Key` I am fetching the Json using Google's http-client library and it turns out if I do `Map<String, FooInfo> dict = (Map<String, FooInfo>) response.parseAs(new TypeToken<HashMap<String, FooInfo>>() {}.getType());` and this works which is doubly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got that `@Key` annotation from, but Gson uses [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

After making that change, I have the class:

```
public class FooInfo {
    @SerializedName("foo_sticks")
    public String fooSticks;

    @SerializedName("bar_socks")
    public String[] barSocks;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FooInfo [fooSticks=" + fooSticks + ", barSocks=" + Arrays.toString(barSocks) + "]";
    }
}
```

Then, parsing the JSON:

```
{ 
    "arbitray_key_name": {
        "foo_sticks": "objectName",
        "bar_socks": ["A", "B"]
    },
    "another_key_name": {
        "foo_sticks": "differentName",
        "bar_socks": ["C", "D", "E"]
    }
}
```

I can properly read in the object:

```
HashMap<String, FooInfo> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, FooInfo>>() {}.getType());
System.out.println(map);
```

And get your expected output:

```
{another_key_name=FooInfo [fooSticks=differentName, barSocks=[C, D, E]], arbitray_key_name=FooInfo [fooSticks=objectName, barSocks=[A, B]]}
```

Comment: As I said in my comment above I'm using this in conjunction with Google's http-client lib which wants the Key Annotation.  Using `@SerializedNames` works for the use case I laid out in my question, thanks.

Using @Key worked with http-client when using the correct `parseAs` method as I described in my comment